# RJ45 PCB Design Transformer & MagJack

Tags: pcb, rj45

Designing a PCB board that supports RJ45 using W5500, yet I'm confused with two issues:

1. Magnetic jack: Is it required?
2. Is transformer required if Magnetic jack is used? Or are they unrelated?

By checking W5500 I noticed they are using a non-magnetic jack in the schematic.

Answer (score 3):

You mean Ethernet interface and it must have transformer coupling.

1. No, a jack with integrated magnetics is not mandatory, but then you must have  a separate transformer
2. No, there must not be a separate transformer if there already is a jack with integrated magnetics.

Comment: Is it truly that there *must* not be a separate transformer if you use a magjack, or is it just that it's not necessary?

Comment: For an ethernet interface there must also be correct DC termination, and the secondary is normally grounded. If you correctly connect DC termination and grounding you also add another transformer:  without correct grounding and DC termination it won't work.

Comment: @Hearth I guess if you want to do something extremely special and extremely carefully select a suitable transformer with specific specs, I guess it is possible to put two sets of magnetics and still be a legal Ethernet device within specs. As an example, connecting a standard Ethernet device and a PoE injector/extractor as separate modules to make a device with single Ethernet port.

Comment: @Justme Yeah, I couldn't think of any reason you *would* do that, but I did want to know if it was disallowed by the specification or something, since you said "must not".